# Creating an installer for a Java app

Tags: java, deployment, installation

I need an advice here.

I need to create an installer for a Java application. After googling around a bit, I landed at [these](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators) [pages](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/java-concepts/34-core-java/63-make-an-installer-for-your-java-applications.html). After analyzing a little, I decided to go with [IzPack](http://izpack.org/). I found [this](http://sonalimendis.blogspot.in/2010/05/write-installer-with-izpack.html) nice blog post using which I was able to create a decent installer stub.

However I am now stuck with the further development. I need to customize my installer in several ways, and I am sure they're possible with IzPack, but I cannot figure out the ways to do it. The IzPack mailing list and its stackoverflow tag has a very low activity, and the documentation is very poor.

So I ditched IzPack, and started writing my own installer manually. After writing only two frames, I am realizing this will take much more time and might not be feasible.

Do you know of any other installer generator that has a better documentation and community support? Or do you know any good resources and links on IzPack where I can have my questions answered? Or do you suggest I stick with the custom installer approach? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), it have a good documentation and commercial support ...

Another valid alternative to create a multi platform installer could be BitRock Installer ([InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/)) .

Comment: Install4J's licence costs are a bit too high for our budget. Can InstallBuilder be used for Java applications?

Comment: Yes, InstallBuilder can be used even for Java application. Is one of the best installer platform out there ...

Comment: It appears even BitRock installer has a costly licence. I should have mentioned that I am looking for free-of-cost solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on windows, take a look at [iexpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress)

To try it out press *alt* and simply type *iexpress* and press enter

Comment: I need to write an installer that works on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Look to [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). It is cross-platform and has good support (on SO), as well as good support from the manufacturer (Sun/Oracle).  I don't know if it fits the other requirements of this installation, but might know more when you specify those requirements.

Comment: I haven't looked into it yet. Thanks for the pointer. I'll have a look!