# How make an installer for a java application?

Tags: java, mysql, installation

I made a netbeans java application (javax.swing), connecting to the mysql database. The connection is made through localhost. Now I would like to create an installer for this application. In order to install my project on other computers.

What do I need to do in order to create an installer? 
I'll have to make some kind of change in the database, or connection?

Do you know any simple program? I've been researching this: http://www.clickteam.com/install-creator-2

Thank you all for your help.

If someone did not understand my question, I try to explain better. 
I apologize for the inconvenience.

Greetings.

Comment: Take a look at the options suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752531/creating-an-installer-for-a-java-app

Comment: Thanks for reply. You think will be necessary to make some type of change to the database? Because a doubt mine is how I will create the program database. Because the connection I have at the moment is localhost.

Comment: Indeed, database complicates the task. The easiest way is to ask user for database connection params on one of your installer's screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- right click in you project;
- click on "Clean and Build";
- After that go to the netbeans project folder;
- It creats a new folder called: "Dist"
- In this folder will have a file ProjectName.Jar (Does an executable of your
  application);
- After that run the program you mentioned, this will transform executable "ProjectName.Jar" into an installer.

For that try this tutorials:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8ccin6w4JM&list=PLB04B4E5D9B58C13D&index=114

In this videos you will find a very simple way to create an executable and an installer of your application.